# Teradata SQL Assistant - NOT EXISTS, INNER JOIN, IN or other way

Tags: sql, union, teradata, except, not-exists

There is a table with data about cars.

| model_id | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | black |
| 1 | green |
| 2 | black |
| 3 | blue |
| 3 | white |
| 4 | red |
| 5 | white |
| 5 | black |

The task is that if the model can be black, then leave only it (black), and if the model cannot be black, then leave all its colors:

| model_id | color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | black |
| 2 | black |
| 3 | blue |
| 3 | white |
| 4 | red |
| 5 | black |

The first way:

`create table black_cars as`

`(select * from cars where color = 'black')`

`with data;`

`create table not_black_cars as (`

`select c.* from cars as c`

`where not exists (select 1 from black_cars as bc where bc.model_id = c.model_id)`

`with data;`

`select * from black_cars`

`union`

`select * from not_black_cars;`

The second way:

`select * from cars where color = 'black`

`union`

`select * from cars as c`

`inner join`

`(select distinct model_id from cars except select model_id from cars where color = 'black') as nbc`

`on c.model_id = nbc.model_id`

The third way (low performance):

`select * from cars where color = 'black`

`union`

`select * from cars where model_id not in`

`(select model_id from cars where color = 'black)`

I am far from sure that either of these ways is optimal. I would be very grateful if someone could suggest the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use:

```
select c.*
from cars c
where c.color = 'black' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from cars c2
                  where c2.model_id = c.model_id and
                        c2.color = 'black'
                 );
```

In many cases, you might find that window functions have good performance:

```
select c.*
from cars c
qualify c.color = 'black' or
        sum(case when c.color = 'black' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by c.model_id) = 0;
```

As for which of all the versions has the best performance -- well you have to try them on your data and your system.  It depends on many factors:

- The indexes on the table.
- The size of the table.
- The average number of colors per model.
- The distribution of the number of black/non-black colors across models.

And probably more.  One of the above seems reasonable -- as do your methods that don't involve temporary tables.

Comment: Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach based on OLAP-functions, which can easily be extended to more complex logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
QUALIFY
   Rank() 
   Over (PARTITION BY model_id
         -- preferred condition first
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN color = 'black' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC) = 1
;
```

Performance of OLAP-functions in Teradata is probably as good or better than EXISTS, etc. based solutions. Only a PI on the PARTITION BY column(s) might beat it, mainly depending on the number of rows per value.